# How to pass a path from VBA to $ARGV [0] in Perl

Tags: excel, vba, windows, argv

I want to memories the path of my Excel file by using command line arguments `argv[0]`,
in order to use it after by Perl, How do I do this in VBA please?
I have this proposition, but it doesn't work !

```
#code VBA :
Sub Import_Dico_Csv()
Dim path As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    my.application.commandlineargs.item(0) = path     'argv[0]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but you can create an Environment Variable with VBA which the perl script can then use.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Env_MyXLSPath()
    
    Dim cmd As String
    cmd = "SETX MYXLSPATH """ & ThisWorkbook.FullName & """"
    'Debug.Print cmd
    Shell cmd

End Sub
```

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
print $ENV{'MYXLSPATH'}."\n";
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
but I don't find the key 'MYXLSPATH' in my variable %ENV
i have only and always 44 keys 
scalar %ENV == 44

Comment: @lunched Did you run the VBA first ?

Comment: yes
may i have to change the name "SETX MYXLSPATH " by another keys??

Comment: What OS windows. ? Do you have permission to create env variables ?  How are you running perl , in commnd window ? Why can you not use a json or yaml file ?

Comment: Édition Windows 10 Famille, Version 20H2;
Yes, i have permission;
I run the  commands "perl 1.pl", in  Windows CMD;
I need to use 'xlsm' file;

Comment: @lunched open a new cmd window type SET which will list the env variables see if myxlspath is there. I meant use a json or yaml file to hold the value that you trying to send from excel to perl.

Comment: sorry, I found it, but it's in my user variables and not a systeme variables.
what can I right please in perl to found it ?